# How to specify specific projects in build settings for web deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have created a new release build in TFS 2013 and I want to configure it to perform a web deploy. I am not sure how to specify which project to deploy. Ideally I want to web deploy 2 web projects to IIS on the server (both projects will have a corresponding website in IIS), but if it not possible I can live with having 2 separate builds. I have added the following setings to MSBuild Arguments (in Advanced section of the process) in build definition:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:Configuration=Release 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True  
/p:DeployIisAppPath="<IISSIteName>" 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<my server IP>/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:username=Administrator 
/p:password=xxxxx
```

I can see it is conneting fine, but it doesn't publish anything. I also tried to specify my web project in Items to build section, but that didn't help. What am I missing? Must be some setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you have 2 web projects in the solution and you want to create build definition to deploy them as two different web sites on IIS server.

There could be better ways of handling this but what I have done in my project is to have two separate build definitions for 2 web projects.
For each build definition, specify the csporj file of the project to build under “items to build” section of the process tab.

Even after doing this TFS may not publish the web site at desired location. It may show success but files won’t be copied to the destination location. 
In this case, check the log messages of the build activity. If you find a warning similar to this: 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (484, 9): warning: The OutputPath property is not set for project ProjectName.csproj'.
Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. Configuration='Release' Platform='Any CPU'

Then it may be related to build configuration. If you are using “Any CPU” as build configuration then change it to “AnyCPU” (remove space).

Refer following link for the detailed explanation:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0bb277ec-a08c-4795-88f0-3207654e2560/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-project-xxxxxbtproj-please-check-to-make-sure-that-you?forum=tfsbuild

Amey

Comment: I have already figured this out. I created a build and used a publish profile with the same name for both web apps and it seems to work.